# Gitlab: how to take difference between latest and previous pipeline commits

Tags: git, gitlab

ive looking for method which i can use for getting all comments texts from commits added with last build pipeline in gitlab

we can take commits sha key by using gitlab api, but this request dont getting any information about commit comments (sha key holding changed commits id):

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ********" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/latest"

{"id":442495,"sha":"e6b81550c9251b88a273ba6c86938769a76f9d15","ref":"master","status":"success","created_at":"2021-01-21T09:15:09.290+03:00","updated_at":"2021-01-21T09:15:27.869+03:00","web_url":"https://gitlab.example.com/ci/testproject/-/pipelines/442495","before_sha":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","tag":false,"yaml_errors":null,"user":{"id":369,"name":"John, Doe","username":"jdoe","state":"active","avatar_url":"****","web_url":"****","finished_at":"2021-01-21T09:15:27.857+03:00","committed_at":null,"duration":6,"coverage":null,"detailed_status":{"icon":"status_success","text":"passed","label":"passed","group":"success","tooltip":"passed","has_details":false,"details_path":"/ci/testproject/-/pipelines/123456","illustration":null,"favicon":"/assets/ci_favicons/favicon_status_success-8451333011eee8ce9f2ab25dc487fe24a8758c694827a582f17f42b0a90446a2.png"}}
```

at completed result we should get all text included in commits comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gitlab has a Commits API that you can use to get all commits in a project, or retrieve a single commit from it's sha. For your use case, after you get the commits for the pipeline, you can run each one through the "get single commit" API to get the title/message (or any other part) as needed. You can also run the commit sha through the Commits Comments operation to get comments on that commit.

The details for the Commits API and the Get Single Commit operation are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit

The Commit Comments operation is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-the-comments-of-a-commit

Comment: i used git log with describe method and its work fine, thanks for advice with api! construct with git log describe can be used inside gitlab\ci

Comment: is there any way to get the last commit or last pipeline directly?